# Styled divs not appearing

Tags: html, css, web

Why is the following CSS code not working with these divs? They don't seem to appear at all when I open the site although everything else on the external CSS file on my HTML file is working in divs...

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you!

**CSS:**

```
.leftAd
{

width: 200px;
height: 300px;   
padding: 5px;
border: 3px solid black;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 4%;
margin-right: 15%;
border-radius: 10px; 
background-color: white;

}

.rightAd
{

width: 200px;
height: 300px;   
padding: 5px;
border: 3px solid black;
text-align: center;
margin-right: 4%;
border-radius: 10px; 
background-color: white;

}

.rightAlign
{

float: right;

}
```

**CSS Continued:**

```
.leftAlign
{

float: left;

}

.text
{

font-family: text;
font-size: 25px;
color: white; 

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="leftAd leftAlign text"></div> 

<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div class="rightAd rightAlign text"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using an adblocking browser plugin. They typically will block classes like the ones you're using.

Comment: Yes infact I actually am!

Comment: @Paulie_D I know, I know, but what else can I say?

Comment: How would I stop this if I use adblock?

Comment: @Paulie_D - There, less commenty

Comment: @loltroll - Try using classnames without "ad". Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qw85m6g1/

Comment: That does not work, I renamed leftAd, and rightAd to hjjhkjh1, and hjjhkjh2 and they still don't show up! What do I do next in order to solve this problem?

Comment: @j08691, can you please add more keywords to your answer, ref SEO?